# How to change $stateparams so that it displays in URL, but doesn't actually change the state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state

I would like to be able to modify the URL of my page based on user actions. I could do this by invoking `$state.go(state, toParams)`, but this involves actually changing the state. I think that is overkill since in this case I'm not actually changing my state, I'm just changing the `statparams`.

So how can I change the `stateparams` such that it displays in the URL, but doesn't actually trigger a state change?

Comment: If `stateparams` are changed, then the state should be reloaded. It's OK, you should not have to worry about it.

If you bother about http requests (that should be fulfilled to resolve the state), then cache it!